# A Database group by mode sql Error Occurred

Tags: php, laravel

Im facing following error while running the my php code on cpanel shared hosting. im using shared hosting so cant change group by mode setting. i also changed 'strict' => false, in database.php file

#Error

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1140

In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'whitepel_servepel.f.currency_code'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
SELECT sum(fee) as paid_amt, `currency_code` 
FROM `subscription_details_history` as `s` 
JOIN `subscription_fee` as `f` ON `f`.`id`=`s`.`subscription_id`
```

Filename: models/Dashboard_model.php

Line Number: 313

#Line 313 code is this

```
public function get_payment_info(){
        $ret = '';
        $query=$this->db->select('sum(fee) as paid_amt, currency_code')->from('subscription_details_history as s')->join('subscription_fee as f','f.id=s.subscription_id')->get();

        if($query !== FALSE && $query->num_rows() > 0){
            $ret = $query->result_array();
        }
        return $ret;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server probably has [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) turned on. You can either turn it off or add each of your selected fields to the group by.

Comment: i appreciate your answer. but im using shared hosting so i cant turn off. and to be honest im not developer it could be appreciate if you edit above code for me . it would be great thankful.